# How to connect to a "Private" screen session

Tags: 16.04, gnu-screen

I have a couple of machines starting screen sessions for individual users. I do this by running

```
su news -c "screen -d -m -S news /usr/local/bin/newstask"
```

Normally, I can attach to such screen using

```
screen -r news/newstask
```

However, on one machine, this produces an error:

```
# screen -r news/newstask
There is a screen on:
        2341.newstask   (07.08.2016 11:28:33)   (Private)
There is no screen to be attached matching newstask.
```

What is strange is that the session is shown as "(Private").

Typically, they are tagged "(Multi, detached"). From another machine:

```
# screen -ls news/
There are several suitable screens on:
        8973.newstask   (07.08.2016 11:16:46)   (Multi, detached)
        1864.newsclient        (07.08.2016 03:03:23)   (Multi, detached)
        1850.newsserver        (07.08.2016 03:03:23)   (Multi, detached)
3 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-news.
```

What could be the reason for why these sessions are tagged (Private), and how can I attach to these? Or how could I avoid the sessions being private?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this https://superuser.com/questions/193798/is-it-possible-to-make-a-screen-session-private is what you hit. GNU Screen can have password protected sessions.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `screen` doesn't let you attach to a session from another user.  In order to do so, you have to use the commands `multiuser` and `addacl` (see the `screen(1)` manual page).

In your case, assuming you want user `root` to be able to access screens from user `news`, you will have to add these lines to `~news/.screenrc`:

```
multiuser on
addacl root
```